# Comments social plugin for Action post

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments

I have an app `app1` which defines a custom Facebook action `act1`.

When a user performs this action to an entity (ntt1) in my app, I post to API `/me/app1:act1` with URL to `ntt1` as its param, so that a post is generated on user's wall saying `User act1'ed ntt1` where ntt1 is a link to ntt1's **view** page (with open graph meta data on its header).

Users can comment or like on this wall post regularly.

Now I want to show users' comments on ntt1's web page as well to share the comments and likes between the Facebook wall and ntt1's view page.

I tried using the Comments social plug-in, but don't know what to put in the data-href to point to the  `action_instance_id`  of the wall post.

I know I can simulate a comments box on my page using the graph API (and I've already done so), but this is not making a good ux, because the users need to authorize to my application to view this page (so that the java script API can fetch the comments from the Facebook).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just pointing the data-href attribute to

```
https://www.facebook.com/{user_name_or_id}/activity/{action-instance-id}
```

…? The [docs for using actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/) say this is the URL you can use to “preview” the news feed story that this published action will generate (or rather *has already* generated, because without publishing the action first, you would not have an action-instance-id).

If you click on the “x minutes/hours/… ago” link for the feed story for one of your published actions, it should take you to a link that’s build using the same scheme.

Comment: Thanks for your response. No! It doesn't work.
This is making a very big problem for the whole project.